# Print multiple images in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

In VB.NET, I need to print multiple Images of bar codes by arranging them in tabular format. For now what I am doing is, Creating the bar codes and adding them in new picture box. These Picture boxes are added on a panel which I am creating on form at run time and print that panel (with picture boxes in 4x9 table).

But, when I need to print more that 36 bar codes, this idea doesn't work.

So, Please suggest me some improvements in my code or any other way to do this job.

---

I am sorry, here is the code for generating images and adding them to the panel..

```
''' Method for create bar code images with a loop and adding them to the panel by picture box...    
Private Function GetBarcodeText(RowId As Guid)  
        Dim BarcodeValue As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(96)  
        Dim temp As New StringBuilder  
        Dim data As String  
        Dim param = New SqlParameter()  
        Dim imageNo As Integer = 0  
        Dim colorValue As String = ""  
        Dim scaleValue As String = ""  

    '' Adding the panel on the form which is dynamically created
    Me.Controls.Add(outputPanel)

    '' Setting the Initial size for the panel
    outputPanel.Size = New Point(794, 112)
    outputPanel.Name = "outputPanel"
    outputPanel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    param.ParameterName = "@RowId"
    param.Value = RowId
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier

    ' Get the particular row of data from database
    dt = objStockProvider.GetBarcodeDetails(param)

    ' GET colour code
    Dim color As String = dt.Rows(0)("COLOUR").ToString()

    Dim countColors As Integer = 0
    ' Get the color code numbers
    param.ParameterName = "@Dscale"
    param.Value = dgvViewTickets.CurrentRow.Cells("SCALE").Value.ToString()
    countColors = objStockProvider.CountColorCodes(param)

    For i = 1 To countColors
        For j As Integer = 1 + ((12 / countColors) * (i - 1)) To (12 / countColors) * i
            If dt.Rows(0)("S" + j.ToString()) <> 0 Then
                Dim totalTicketsForASize As Integer
                totalTicketsForASize = dt.Rows(0)("S" + j.ToString())
                For k As Integer = 1 To totalTicketsForASize                     
                    ' Set Bar code value which has to create
                    BarcodeValue = "123456789012"
                    ' Create Barcode Image for given value
                    Dim image = GetBarcodeImage(BarcodeValue, colorValue, scaleValue)
                    If image IsNot Nothing Then
                        '' Create picture box to contain generated Image.
                        Dim pcbImage As New PictureBox
                        pcbImage.Width = W
                        pcbImage.Height = H
                        pcbImage.Image = image
                        pcbImage.Location = New Point(X, Y)
                        imageNo += 1
                        If imageNo Mod 4 = 0 Then
                            X = 15
                            Y += H
                            outputPanel.Height += H
                        Else
                            X += W
                            Y = Y
                        End If
                        pcbImage.Visible = True
                        '' Adding picture box to panel
                        outputPanel.Controls.Add(pcbImage)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
        color = color.Substring(color.IndexOf(",") + 1, color.Length - color.IndexOf(",") - 1)
    Next
    PrintGeneratedTickets()
End Function
```

Now, I am printing the panel by following method:

```
Private Sub PrintGeneratedTickets()

    bmp = New Bitmap(outputPanel.DisplayRectangle.Width, outputPanel.DisplayRectangle.Height)
    Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

    G.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.outputPanel.DisplayRectangle.Width, Me.outputPanel.DisplayRectangle.Height))
    Dim Hdc As IntPtr = G.GetHdc()
    SendMessage(outputPanel.Handle, WM_PRINT, Hdc, DrawingOptions.PRF_OWNED Or DrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN Or DrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT Or DrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT)
    G.ReleaseHdc(Hdc)
    pndocument.DocumentName = bmp.ToString()

    Dim previewmode As New PrintPreviewDialog
    previewmode.Document = pndocument
    previewmode.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    previewmode.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1

    pndocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 10
    pndocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 30
    pndocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 16
    pndocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 16
    pndocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
    ' Set other properties.
    previewmode.PrintPreviewControl.Columns = 4
    previewmode.PrintPreviewControl.Rows = 9

    previewmode.ShowDialog()

    Dim file As String = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    file = Path.GetFullPath("D:\Bar Codes\" + file.Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", ".") + ".bmp")
    bmp.Save(file)
    G.Dispose()
    outputPanel.Controls.Clear()

End Sub
```

This code is working fine but what I need to do, is to fix the number of images (4x9) per page. But when I am trying to create more than it, that all are printing on a single page with compressed size.

Also when trying to re-run the code, It shows nothing in preview..

Some body please suggest the correction in code so that I can reprint the tickets and use paging for more than 36 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Printing the Images on a panel was not a good idea.. I replaced the panel and created an array of images and used the print document directly and print after arranging images on it.

Thanks.